# Routing function gets stuck in infinite loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to learn AngularJS and this is the code I have written:

```
myApp.config(function($routeProvider){
    console.log('--Inside config--');
    $routeProvider
    .when('/',{
        templateUrl: 'index.html'
    })
    .when('/list', {
        templateUrl: 'list.html'
    })
    .when('/detail', {
        templateUrl: 'detail.html'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
});
```

When I view this in Chrome, the JS console shows that it has gone into infinite loop and freezes. As soon as I remove this function, it comes up fine. Any help?

Comment: This looks fine. Are you sure it's the problem?

Comment: Can you create a Plunkr showing the problem?

Comment: I have a theory on what's the issue, let me know if I'm right - my html file is named index.html, which has the div with 'ng-view' tag. So when the location url is '/' it loads the index.html, and then again (because of the JS routing function above) tries to load index.html within the <div ng-view> of the page, and it goes on.. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, in the HTML file:

```
<html ng-app="My_App">
<head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js" data-semver="1.0.7"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>        
    <script src="<path to test.js>/test.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-view>
</body>
</html>
```

test.js:

```
var app = angular.module('My_App', []);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){

$routeProvider
.when('/main',{
    templateUrl: 'partials/main_navigation/main.html',
    controller: 'main' // If you want to use controllers
)
.when('/menu',{
    templateUrl: 'partials/main_navigation/menu.html',
    controller: 'menu' // If you want to use controllers
).otherwise({redirectTo: '/main'});
```